# What is the canonical way of writing a tree recursion in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, tree

The following code example shows a part of a binary tree example, which manage "tweets". Each node of the tree is checked whether it fits the predicate (p). If a tweet fits the predicate, then it will be accumulated (acc) to a new tree set. On the other hand, if p = false, it will simply go to the next node.

```
def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    var result = acc
    if(p(elem)){
      result = right.filterAcc(p, result incl elem)
      result = left.filterAcc(p, result incl elem)
      }else {
      result = right.filterAcc(p, result)
      result = left.filterAcc(p, result)
      }
    result
  }
```

The program is called as follows, whereas p is a passed function:

```
filterAcc(p, new Empty)
```

My question is, what is a canonical way in Scala for recursion? In particular of passing back the result to the highest level of the recursion.

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean "recursion". And I've no idea what your actual question is. You pass back the result from he lowest level  and the next lowest level passes that back and so on...

Comment: BTW, the use of "var" here is definitely non-canonical. I'd just write `if (p(elem)) left.filterAcc(p, right.filterAcc(p, acc, incl elem)) else ...` (there's no need to add `elem` twice))}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember the interface of this classes from Coursera courses and assuming you actually meant `recursion` (not `regression`) it should go like this:

```
def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
  val updatedAcc = if(p(elem)) acc.incl(elem) else acc // visit current node
  left.filterAcc(p, right.filterAcc(p, updatedAcc))    // continue tree traversal
}
```

As you can explicitly see in this code the main intention is to call the same function with modified parameter. We change `acc` parameter based on the fact if we met tweet satisfying `p` or not. After that we have to iterate to the `right` subtree (`right.filterAcc(p, updatedAcc)`), get the result of iteration (pass it to the next side iteration), iterate to the left (`left.filterAcc(p, right.filterAcc(p, acc))`) subtree.